# A single word for someone who is loved quickly by everyone?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

If someone who loves quickly can be called openhearted, what do you call someone who is loved quickly? I can only think of the words which are probably reasons to someone being loved, such as **adorable**, **kind**, or maybe **famous**.

I know some friends who are loved really quickly by people around them. They include ladies, and gentlemen.

So, apart from the condition of the people around that someone (which are probably openhearted), or that someone is an adorable human being, what do you refer to someone who is loved quickly?

Comment: What's wrong with [lovable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovable)?

Comment: Do you mean like the Dos Equis man or Austin Powers? Every man wants to be them, every woman wants to be with them? Life of the party?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[*Charming*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charming) comes to mind: very pleasing; delightful. (The synonyms of this word attest to its strength: *beguile*, *bewitch*, *captivate*, *enchant*, *entrance*, *fascinate*.)

> He could charm the birds out of the trees.

[*Charismatic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charismatic): possessing an extraordinary ability to attract. (Again, synonyms attest to its power: charming, appealing, attractive, influential, **magnetic**, enticing, alluring. *With her striking looks and charismatic personality, she was noticed far and wide.*) This word has been associated with Christian denominations, however, decreasing its appeal to some.

> By virtue of his charm and charisma, Kennedy overcame anti-Catholic prejudice to win the presidency in 1960.

Answer (score 8):

The closest word that matches your description is *lovable*.

> Inspiring or deserving love or affection

A lovable person is, by definition, easily and therefore quickly loved--though not necessarily by everyone, as not everyone loves lovable people. You would have to add additional words or phrases to say a particular person is unanimously loved.

Here are some quotes from Google Books showing its usage:

> "Mary was extremely lovable!" Jane burst out angrily. "She had more...natural charm than anyone I've ever met. Everyone loved her--you couldn't help it." (Reveley, "The Etruscan Couple, and Other Stories")
>
> "That commitment is not arbitrary, but the natural consequence of the conviction that God is love, that everyone is loved by God and that everyone is thus lovable." (Søren Kierkegaard, Eighteen Upbuilding Discourses)

Answer (score 5):

"Endearing" is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You could use affable, amiable.

Comment: Affable and Amiable make the best sense!

Answer (score 4):

Consider "[sweetheart](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweetheart)" and "[sweetie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sweetie)" for nouns, and "[lovable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovable)," "[likable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likable)," "[lovely](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lovely)," and the rarer, somewhat obsolescent and/or US dialectal  "[likely](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/likely)," in the way of adjectives.

> [Uncle Peck is extremely likable, and it's easy to see, because of his respectful and easy spoken tones, how Lil' bit could fall for him.](http://www.theslant.com/arts_media/archive.html)
>
> [A tow truck operator would have plenty of opportunities to meet community leaders. And Steve was such a likable man, who obviously made friends easily.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=YV-MZRVYwjwC&pg=PT73&lpg=PT73&dq=%22such+a+likable+man%22&source=bl&ots=Mh8BVRSnBW&sig=wBi_vAU77j5-xfvM9CqLzAgESIU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=PiJaU8SlE8LG0QX6uIDoBg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22such%20a%20likable%20man%22&f=false)
>
> [He was such a lovable man; women had a hard time resisting him.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Gql-u9_znl4C&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=%22such+a+lovable+man%22&source=bl&ots=sqTwiTLdzj&sig=mWGQf2kfXpX1mzx10nZ5JHl3Sbc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=diNaU_LxDoeW0QWKkoHoBQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22such%20a%20lovable%20man%22&f=false)
>
> [He said she [Carole Embry Hamilton] was such a likely person and her smile was contagious.](https://www.facebook.com/RememberingCaroleEmbryHamilton?filter=2)

That sudden love inspiring feeling can also be conveyed through such adjectives as [genial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genial) and [congenial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congenial).

Answer (score 0):

I think the word ["appealing"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appealing) could suit you:

> evoking or attracting interest, desire, curiosity, sympathy, or the like; attractive.

This word can express both social and physical atractiveness.

Answer (score 0):

What about *popular*?

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/popular) says:

> appealing to the general public; widely favoured or admired

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/popular_1):

> liked, enjoyed, or supported by many people

The word can be applied to many things (for example, popular legislation, popular music, or a popular restaurant), but it can also be used as an adjective to describe a person:

> a popular person is liked by most people ([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/popular))

There's also this definition, on the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/popular) page:

> Liked by acquaintances; sought after for company: *"Beware of over-great pleasure in being popular or even beloved"*

That definition suggests *beloved* might be a good word, too.

One other suggestion (but I saved it for the bottom, because it's not a single word): *naturally likeable*. The adverb *naturally* suggests that this person isn't likeable simply because they are trying too hard, or being overly generous, but because they have a genuine, innate affability.

Answer (score 0):

Adored?  It is platonic in it's meaning. So it works for non-sexual situations too.

> love, be very fond of, be very keen on, be partial to, have a weakness for;
>
> delight in, relish, savor;
>
> *informal* be crazy about, be wild about, have a thing about/for/with, be hooked on
>
> "I adore oysters"`

Sorry IE is not showing me any of my editing tools

Answer (score -1):

I like *prepossessing*.  It seems to be exactly what you are trying to convey!

Answer (score -1):

*Charismatic* perhaps shades more to power than love, but it touches the masses.

Answer (score -3):

*Prostitute*, if you’re thinking in somewhat literal terms.

Comment: I don't see how that's literal.